# Question about a non-sorting jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, datatable

I am using the datatable plugin for jQuery, I have a table on my html page that I dont want sorting on, but I am using the plugin to paginate the results, and also have verbage if there is nothing in the table.  I have no problem stopping the table from sorting using ("bSort": false), but it still makes the header of the tables clickable, which can be frustrating to the user because there is no change when clicked.  Here is the plugin I am using: http://datatables.net/ , and here is my HTML:

```
  <table align="center" id="t1" width="57%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="headerClass" width="12%">Type</th>
        <th class="headerClass">Description</th>
        <th class="headerClass" width="3%">Campus</th>
        <th class="headerClass" width="14%">Date </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="normal"><%=lostFound%></td>
        <td class="normal"><%=lostDesc%></td>
        <td class="normal"><%=lostLoc%></td>
        <td class="normal"><%=lostDate%></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And here is my jS:

```
  var $t1 = $("#t1");
    $t1.dataTable({
      "bSort": false, 
      "oLanguage" : bsLfReq.O_LANGUAGE, 
      "bLengthChange": false, 
      "bFilter": false, 
      "bAutoWidth": false, 
      "iDisplayLength": 3, 
      "bInfo": false
      });
```

So basically I want the table to still use the datatable plugin, but not have the headers clickable.  Is this possible?

Comment: You should mention that your using the this plugin for jQuery --> http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your scenario. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkFbz/).
For me deactivating sorting via `"bSort" : false` works like a charm.

With sorting (see the arrows):[image]
Without sorting:[image]

**UPDATE:**

Define a cursor for your `headerClass`:

```
#headerClass {
   cursor: default;
}
```

Check out [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html) reference for cursor styles.

Comment: right, but unlike that fiddle, I can get the sorting to go away, but the headers are still clickable.  I am using IE, if that makes a difference.

Comment: What do you mean with 'clickable'. Does the hand appear and with a click nothing happens or does it **really** work?

Comment: Yes, the hand will appear, and allow the user to click, but nothing will happen.  Sorry I should have explained that better, lol.

Comment: Wow, not sure exactly how this works, but w/ the update it does. Very interesting, thank you!

Comment: So check out a [CSS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) to get a better understanding of what you can do with CSS.